# ¿Qué métodos hay para mostrar un mensaje con throw?

Tags: php, excepciones

```
if (method_exists($controller, $method ) ) {
    throw new Exception(echo "Error Processing Request";);

}
```

*¿Cuáles son las múltiples prácticas que se pueden usar con `throw` ?*
Bien sea mostrar mensaje de error o llevarnos a otro sitio

Comment: cuando usas trow lo ideal es tener un catch para atraparlo, y entonces en el catch decides que hacer si una redireccion o un log de errores todo depende de lo que deseas pero la idea siempre es usar la estructura try{ event trow new }catch{event error} y listo

Answer (score 5):

Con el `throw` no se muestra el mensaje, sino que se lanza una Excepción en la que puedes añadirle un mensaje y esta Excepción se recogerá en un bloque `catch` donde se podrá mostrar el mensaje o hacer cualquier otra acción.

### Explicación

---

Según la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php) de [php](/questions/tagged/php) y [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp) el modelo de excepciones es similar al de otros lenguajes de programación. Por lo que una excepción puede ser lanzada mediante un `throw` y atrapada por un `catch`. El código puede estar dentro de un bloque `try` para facilitar la captura de excepciones potenciales. Además, cada bloque `try` debe tener al menos un bloque `catch` o un bloque `finally` o ambos.

Esta estructura tendrá la siguiente forma:

```
try{
   .... //código

   throw new Exception('Error X.');

   .... //código

}catch (Exception $e){
   //tratamiento de la excepción
   echo $e->errorMessage(); 
}catch (MyException $me){
   //tratamiento de otra excepción
   displayErrorPage($me->getMessage());
}finally{

}
```

A continuación se explicará un poco cada parte que forma el manejo de excepciones:

1. **Try**: Una función que utiliza una excepción debe estar en un bloque "try". Si la excepción no se activa, el código continuará como de costumbre. Sin embargo, si la excepción se activa, se lanzará una excepción.
2. **Throw**: Así es como se activa una excepción. Cada "lanzamiento" (throw) debe tener al menos una "captura" (catch).
3. **Catch**: Un bloque "catch" recupera una excepción y crea un objeto que contiene la información de la excepción. Se pueden usar múltiples bloques "catch" para atrapar diferentes clases de excepciones.
   Cuando una excepción es lanzada, el código siguiente a la declaración no será ejecutado, y PHP intentará encontrar el primer bloque catch coincidente. Si una excepción no es capturada, se emitirá un Error Fatal de PHP con un mensaje `"Uncaught Exception ..." ("Excepción No Capturada")`, a menos que se haya definido un manejador con [set_exception_handler()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.set-exception-handler.php).
4. **Finally**: se puede utilizar un bloque finally después o en lugar de los bloques catch. El código de dentro del bloque finally siempre se ejecutará después de los bloques try y catch, independientemente de que se haya lanzado una excepción o no, y antes de que la ejecución normal continúe.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<?php
   //Función que lanza una excepción
   function checkNum($number) {
      if($number > 1) {
         throw new Exception("Valor debe ser 1 o inferior");
      }
      return true;
   }

   try {
      checkNum(2);
      //si la excepción es lanzada, este texto no se mostrará
      echo 'Si ves esto, el número es 1 o inferior';
   }    
   catch(Exception $e) {
      echo 'Mensaje: ' .$e->getMessage();
   }
?>
```

La ejecución de este código daría como resultado:

> Mensaje: Valor debe ser 1 o inferior

### **Excepciones personalizadas**

---

Por otro lado también se pueden definir [Excepciones propias](http://php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.extending.php), para ello la nueva clase de excepción debe ser una extensión de la clase de `Excepcion`.

La nueva clase de excepción personalizada hereda las propiedades de la clase `Excepcion` de PHP y además se pueden agregar funciones personalizadas a ella.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<?php 
     class myException extends Exception {   
        public function errorMessage() {
            return 'Esta es una excepción personalizada';   
        } 
     }

     try {  
       if(x != y) {        
           //lanzamos la excepción personalizada
           throw new myException ();   
       } 
     }catch (myException $e) {   
           //mostramos el mensaje
           echo $e->errorMessage(); 
     } 
 ?>
```

La ejecución de este código daría como resultado:

> Esta es una excepción personalizada